# Права доступа для include

Tags: права, php, linux

Столкнулся с проблемой при установке DLE. Оказалось, что при извлечении архива директории получили права по умолчанию 700, но не в этом суть. Поменял везде на `drwxr--r--`, но для `include()` или `get_file_contents()` этого не хватило. Добавил права на исполнение - заработало. Поясните, зачем они этим функциям?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй использовать `<? include_once 'dir/file.php'; ?>`.